# Which package and version I can use to create a contact form in umbraco 4.7

Tags: razor

I am new in umbraco, but I am doing a website and has a problem with contour because my umbraco is old version and would not want to change. Someone knows about any free package in umbraco to help me and can sent email by contact us form.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it yourself. It's very simple. Some TextBox and that's it.

If you want them to look great, there are a lots of jquery plugins, ie : http://uniformjs.com/